# distance calculator application

Tags: iphone

i have an application that takes the user supplied distance and does some mathematical solving to find a total cost for that distance taking in account several variables. does anyone know how to implmement an automatic distance finder based on two inputed address in order to minimize the user input.
thanks

Comment: You mean street addresses? If you're computing the distance / route yourself you must already have road data?

Comment: no i dont, thats the thing im trying to do.
i have the user supply an estimated distance from location to location.
however i would like some sort of distance calculator in place to solve this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you can use the Google map service to get the geo-coordinate of the two places. Then its easy to calculate distance between to place having GPS coordinate.
Use MapKit Geocoder get location and CLLocation framework to calculate distance between two location.